# Do any standards exist to correlate HTTP requests and responses between systems

Tags: http, correlation

Consider a suite of distributed applications that uses HTTPS for communications.  This includes requests from the browser to web applications, and from the web applications to backend SOAP and REST services.

When something goes wrong, say a feature is not working for a specific user, one would like to isolate the events that requests across all the systems in order to find the root cause of the problem. What standards exist to correlate events over HTTP?  If none exist, are there resources available how to implement it reliably between different servers implemented using different technologies?

For example, I'm aware that WCF supports correlation ids when sending SOAP requests, but its unclear whether REST services implemented using WCF or ASP.NET Web API supports correlation ids.

Note: I'm not debugging the system. I'm trying to correlate events (errors, warnings, information) across systems (browser, web server farm, backend servers) so someone supporting the system can diagnose issues. So tools like fiddler or looking at the request/response bodies are out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WCF, you have one set of tools to work with.  If you're using WebSphere or JBoss, you've got a different set of tools.

If you're debugging REST at the procol level, I'd strongly suggest looking at Fiddler:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/213007/Debug-WCF-REST-Service
- http://herbjorn.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/fiddling-with-fiddler-debugging-rest-services-on-your-machine/

You might also be interested in this thread:

- [how to log JSON response in WCF at service level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602373/how-to-log-json-response-in-wcf-at-service-level)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  I'm not debugging the system but trying to correlate events (errors, warnings, information) for a request/transaction across different systems to that I can diagnose the issue.  Those events may never appear in fiddler or HTTP requests and responses.